# Fire & Forget calls in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a long running task in an Azure function which I want to run in a background thread using Task.Run. I don't care about the result.

```
public static async Task Run(...)
{
 var taskA = await DoTaskA();     
 Task.Run(new Action(MethodB));
 ....
 // return result based on taskA
}
```

Is this an acceptable pattern in Azure functions? (this is an HTTP trigger function)

I know this could also be done by adding a message to a queue and have another function execute this task but I want to know the pros and cons of starting run long running tasks in a background thread in Azure functions.

Comment: From a client perspective, you just want to trigger the HTTP function to start some task and have it return a 200 OK what it got started?

Comment: @Kzrystof The function will return a status code depending on what happens in DoTaskA. But in this function I also want to execute MethodB & I don't care what happens inside it. (I have updated the question)

Answer (score 6):

It might be best to have an `Azure Function` running `TaskA` and have it post a message in a `ServiceBus` which would trigger another `Azure Function` running `TaskB` when something is posted in that `ServiceBus` since no answer is needed anyway.

Here is the example shown on [microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus):

```
[FunctionName("FunctionB")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem, 
    TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    MethodB();
}
```

In that situation, you do not have to start a new task. Just call `MethodB()`.

That will give you the flexibility the adjust the Plan of your `Azure Functions` (App Service vs Consumption Plan) and minimize the overall cost.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how complex your scenario is, you may want to look into [Durable Functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/v2.x/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.UnitTests/MessageProcessorTests.cs). Durable Functions gives you greater control over a variety of scenarios, including long-running tasks.

Comment: Wont durable funcs also at the core a normal function on AZ and adhere to the same max runtime settings?

Answer (score 2):

No, no and no.

Have your HTTP triggered function return a `202 Accepted`, the results of which you post to a blob URL later on. The 202 should include a `Location` header that points to the *soon to exist* blob URL and maybe a [`Retry-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) header as well if you have a rough idea how long the processing takes.

The long processing task should be a queue triggered function. Why? Because things don't always go according to plan and you may need to retry processing. Why not have the retry built in.